# Typescript React: Infer props from generic component type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, types, styled-components

### Sumary

I'm making a lib that works like stitches, where you can create styled components with classes:

```
import {styled} from 'my-package'

const Text = styled("div", "text-slate-700 font-sans");
```

My question is regarding the type inference from this function. As you noticed, it recieves a string or an component in the first argument and the objective was to get the props of the component passed in the first argument.

### How it should work

I could reproduce what I want with simple objects:

```
type ComponentType = 
  | keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
  | React.ComponentType<any>;

const type: ComponentType = "div";

// It infer the types form the "div" string
type ComponentProps = React.ComponentPropsWithRef<typeof type>;

// Here it works !
const props: ComponentProps = {
  onChange: (e) => console.log(e.target),
};
```

### My problem

But when I tried to pass the same thing using the `React.forwardRef` function, the props comes as type `any`:

```
type ComponentType =
  | keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
  | React.ComponentType<any>;

function _styled(type: ComponentType) {
  return React.forwardRef<
    React.RefAttributes<typeof type>,
    React.ComponentPropsWithRef<typeof type>
  >((props, forwardedRef) => {
    return React.createElement(type, { ...props, ref: forwardedRef });
  });
}
```

If you notice in the image below, vscode tells that the type of props is `any`

[VsCode Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlHyk.png)